# Django Composite Username

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

Is it possible to use two or more fields configured to be unique together as a username in Django? Is this a dumb idea?

Eg;

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    backend = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = backend + user_id  # ???

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('user_id', 'backend')
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make `'username'` a `property`. But since I assume you want it to be the `USERNAME_FIELD` and be able to query the db with it, I'd do something like:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    backend = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=510, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('user_id', 'backend')
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.backend + self.user_id
        super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```